# Animation in Canvas with React plays in an instant then vanishes

Tags: reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a 320x40 .png file that I am trying to play each animation from inside of my canvas, for a total of 10 frames. Each individual animation frame is a 32x40 section of the png file. I'll cut to the chase and show the png animation code for the character:

```
export default function SpriteAni(ctx, charAnim, currentFrame) {

    const charSprite = new Image();
    charSprite.src = `./images/char_${charAnim}.png`

    const posx = 320;
    const posy = 200;
    const sheet_width = 32;
    const sheet_height = 40;
    const sprite_width = sheet_width * 1.5;
    const sprite_height = sheet_height * 1.5;

    ctx.drawImage(charSprite, currentFrame * sheet_width, 0, sheet_width, sheet_height, posx, posy, sprite_width * 1.5, sprite_height * 1.5);
    
}
```

Here's the relevant code for drawing this to the screen inside of my main Canvas.jsx file

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import SpriteAni from '../SpriteAni.jsx';

// Canvas and game logic for display

const Canvas = ({ width, height }) => {

    const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    const requestIdRef = useRef(null);

    let frame = 0;  // frames canvas is drawn to screen

    const [currentFrame, setCurrentFrame] = useState(0); // used to determine current frame for current Wario animation
    const [charAnim, setCharAnim] = useState('walk')

    // Char animation frame counts
    const walk_frames = 9;

    const drawFrame = () => {

        const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d');  

        /// clear screen each frame
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,constants.CANVAS_WIDTH,constants.CANVAS_HEIGHT);

        // draw graphics
        handleBackground(ctx);
        SpriteAni(ctx, charAnim, currentFrame);

        if (currentFrame >= walk_frames) setCurrentFrame(0);
        else setCurrentFrame(currentFrame + 1);
        

    }

    const tick = () => {
        if (!canvasRef.current) return;
        drawFrame();
        frame++;
        requestAnimationFrame(tick)
    }


    useEffect(() => {

        requestIdRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(tick)

        return () => {
            cancelAnimationFrame(requestIdRef.current)
        };
    }, [])



    return (
        <canvas 
            width={width} 
            height={height}
            style={canvasStyle}
            ref={canvasRef}
             />
    )
}

export default Canvas

const canvasStyle = {
    border: "1px solid black",
    position: "absolute",
}
```

What I'm especially confused about is I can delete all of the "if (currentFrame >= `${charAnim}_frames`)..." code underneath SpriteAni in the drawFrame function and nothing changes. It seems to all be acting independently of any of that and just races through all 10 frames before vanishing off of the screen within one second. I don't even understand how that's possible since the only function inside of SpriteAni is a drawImage of which the only variable that *should* be updating each frame is currentFrame.

How is it animating anything independently like that? I'm just baffled what's going on here! Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is `drawFrame()` getting called? My guess at the moment is that you are calling it within the component, so that every time the current frame state updates and the component rerenders, it calls `drawFrame()` again.

Comment: Your `if (currentFrame >= \`${charAnim}_frames\`)...` is also a bit strange because you are comparing `currentFrame` (a number) to `\`${charAnim}_frames\`` (a string), which will always output `false`. Assuming you know the animation is 10 frames, what I think you mean to do is `if (currentFrame >= 10)...`

Comment: You should probably avoid calling `setCurrentFrame(currentFrame + 1)` within the `drawFrame()` function because, as the name entails, it's only job should be to paint the sprite to the canvas. Instead, put `setCurrentFrame(currentFrame + 1)` into a `setTimeout()` callback, so that you can adjust the speed of the animation.

Comment: I just added the entirety of my canvas code just to help with things. I tried replacing `${charAnim}_frames` with 10 but it didn't make any difference. Perhaps my canvas coding is messing things up any. Look at my edit and see if anything sticks out if you can. Thanks to much for trying to help so far!

Comment: `${charAnim}_frames` was my attempt at referring to a const since I'll have other animations I'll refer to depending on the current animation in the animation state variable. I'm just getting back to React after 6 months of quitting so I guess my use of template literals is rusty. I'll look into that!